# It is possible to change the name of the generated variable when nesting regular URL mappings within a resource mapping?

Tags: grails

In order to nest regular URL mappings within a resource mapping, according to the grails [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings) in the url mapping section you can do the following

```
"/books"(resources: "book") {
    "/publisher"(controller:"book", action:'publisher', method: "GET")
}
```

This will produce the following list of urls

```
Controller: book
 |   GET    | /books/create                                     | Action: create              |
 |   GET    | /books/${id}/edit                                 | Action: edit                |
 |   GET    | /books/${bookId}/publisher                        | Action: publisher           |
 |   POST   | /books                                            | Action: save                |
 |   GET    | /books                                            | Action: index               |
 |  DELETE  | /books/${id}                                      | Action: delete              |
 |  PATCH   | /books/${id}                                      | Action: patch               |
 |   PUT    | /books/${id}                                      | Action: update              |
 |   GET    | /books/${id}                                      | Action: show                |
```

As you can see the url generated by `"/publisher"(controller:"book", action:'publisher', method: "GET")` use the variable `bookId` instead of `id` like the other urls.

`/books/${bookId}/publisher`

My question is whether it is possible to change the name of this variable and name it for example `id` like the others

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not used that mapping style personally but I believe the intent of the regular URL mapping within the resource mapping is to do something 'special' with that particular path, in this case `/publisher` (for example you could map it to a different controller altogether, etc)

It sounds like you want it to behave like another standard GET method, so you could add a resource entry like

`get "/books/$id/publisher"(controller:"book", action:"publisher")`

Comment: Thanks for answering, Peter, for the moment I think your recommendation is what should be done, although I would prefer it could be changed as a parameter in the definition of the url.

Comment: in my example, it is set as $id in the definition of the URL - what is the difference you are looking for?

Comment: I mean it would be convenient to define the new name of the variable as a parameter during its definition. For example `"/publisher"(controller:"book", action:'publisher', tokenName: 'id', method: "GET")`

Comment: Which I believe you can do as you like. with `get "/books/$whateverName/publisher"(controller:"book", action:"publisher")`